# window object in NodeJS of SSR got both 'not defined' or 'already been declared'

Tags: node.js

I am migrating an Angular 6 project to Angular Universal project(SSR). In my project, I need to access window object in order to get "navigator", "location", etc... I am using the following method to polyfill window in Server side. But it is not working.

```
try {
  console.log(window);
} catch (window) {
  console.log('Server side window.');

  window = {
    location: {
      replace: () => {},
      protocol: 'https'
    },
    navigator: {
      userAgent: '',
      appVersion: ''
    },
    scrollTo: () => {},
    open: () => {},
    localStorage: {}
  };

  console.log('Server side window.', window);
}
```

What is the best way to handle the window object properly on the server side for the server-side rendering web site? I got following confusion errors. It said 'window is not defined' or 'has been declared'. How to use window object in NodeJS?

```
  > console.log(window);
  ReferenceError: window is not defined
  > let window = 1
  SyntaxError: Identifier 'window' has already been declared
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with this piece of code is that `window` is specified as exception identifier in `try..catch`, basically:

```
try {
  console.log(window);
} catch (window) {
  // window instanceof ReferenceError
  window = {...};
  // window is redefined in this block scope
}
```

This will work in loose mode:

```
try {
  console.log(window);
} catch (err) {
  window = {...};
}
```

But will result in another `ReferenceError` in strict mode. It should be instead:

```
try {
  console.log(window);
} catch (err) {
  global.window = {...};
}
```

And a proper way to detect `window` is:

```
if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
    global.window = {...};
}
```

This code is limited to browser and Node.js; it will result in an error in a worker.